# Swift Codable - Parse JSON which contain array or dictionary type not confirm

Tags: json, swift, codable, decodable, jsondecoder

I am trying to parse JSON which can be

```
"post" : {
    "name" : “Test”,
    "profiePic" : "thumb_small_1526912131.png",
    "to_uni" : "0",
    "id_user" : "2863",
    "post_type" : "0",
    "likes" : [

    ],
    "tags" : [

    ],
    "to_name" : “Vivek”,
    "comments" : [

    ]
  }
```

or it can be of following type

```
"post" : {
    "name" : “Test2”,
    "profiePic" : "thumb_small_1533120835.png",
    "to_uni" : "0",
    "id_user" : "20393",
    "post_type" : "0",
    "likes" : {
      "message" : “Vivek like this."
    },
    "tags" : [

    ],
    "to_name" : “Vv”,
    "comments" : [

    ]
  }
```

So for parse this using JSONDecoder I have created a struct as follows

[Codable Structure dpaste link](http://dpaste.com/1ENR1BE)

And decoding this json as follows

```
do {
                let responses = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: (response?.data!)!)
                print(responses)
            }catch{
                print(error)
            }
```

But i am getting error just for likes value which is **Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.** because that value when blank it returns dictionary when contain value it returns array, so how to manage this kind of case in above struct?

Comment: I'd go by declaring an array of dictionaries for `var likes`. But with a custom init, I'd check if in your JSON it's a single dictionary or an array, and manage the case.

Comment: Just one value when it contains  "message" : “Vivek like this." but as a array @Larme

Comment: `init(from decoder: Decoder) throws { let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self); if let likesAsArray = try? container.decode([Likes].self, forKey: .likes) { self.likes = likesAsArray } else if let singleLike = try? container.decode(Likes.self, forKey: .likes) { self.likes = [singleLike] } else { self.likes = [] }}`?

Comment: where to put this? @Larme

Comment: That's a custom init method. Put it in the `Post` structure.

Comment: this gives me error see this image https://ibb.co/h14Xep @Larme

Comment: You wrote `self =` instead of `self.likes =` the 3 times.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179824/discussion-between-vivek-goswami-and-larme).